# Exception in GRPC when trying to execute Google Cloud API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyinstaller, grpc

I am having a problem when I generate an exe file with pyinstaller. My code runs okay when I execute using the python interpreter but when I generate the exe file using the PyInstaller I get a GRPC error.

> Error:
>   Exception in 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.ssl_roots_override_callback' ignored
>   E0807 20:38:36.262000000 10808 src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.cc:1173] assertion failed: pem_root_certs != nullptr

The error happen when I try to execute a long_running_recognize.

Any tips regarding this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Create hook-grpc.py in the hooks folder (\Lib\site - packages\PyInstaller\hooks) and put the following code.

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files ( 'grpc' )
```

If this doesn't work, then go to \Lib\site - packages\PyInstaller\hooks  and add the following code to hook-google.cloud.py file.

```
datas += copy_metadata ( 'google-cloud-firestore' )
```

Comment: This workaround is working for Windows OS but in Linux same error . Is there any workaround for Linux OS ?  Error: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEIOuPwbX/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem'
E1028 09:36:52.773637848   22762 ssl_utils.cc:577]           assertion failed: pem_root_certs != nullptr
Aborted```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I did the following

1.) create a hook-grpc with the following code

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('grpc')

2.) saved this file the location C:\Users\swap***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks (this will vary as per the installation)

3.) Re create the exe file using the PyInstaller
command to create the file is below

pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py (replace this"pythonScriptName" with your file name)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9223 looks similar with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!